Win32 LoadLibrary, prepend search path for transitive dependencies, without removing PATH env variable
I have a case where I need to load Win32 DLLs into a process. For dependencies of those DLLs, I need the 'default search path' to be in effect, which ends by searching the PATH environmental variable. However, I also need to have the directory of the parent library itself searched.
By default, LoadLibrary does search the PATH environmental variable. But does not search the parent directory of the loading library.
However, passing any of the LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_* functions does not preserve searching in the "standard path". So, any option I can think of to enable LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR in LoadLibrary results in the removal of PATH from the list of candidates. So it seems an either or: search next to loading DLL, or search PATH, but not both.
Is there a work around for this?
The best option I've considered at this point is to manually parse PATH and add it with AddDllDirectory. But that's pretty ugly.

You can add your parent path to the PATH env var with SetEnvironmentVariable().

That wouldn't prepend it. And it would cause PATH to be modified for any children processes, or for other uses like resolving commands. Quite intrusive.

Yes, you would have to read the existing PATH first then prepend/append yours. We've done this in the past with no issues. YMMV.
